# Unable to build Compiled Azure Function in VSTS (Error MSB4019)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Function using the latest build of visual studio 2017 (15.3.1).

This build allows me to do the:

New Project > Azure Function App approach

This produces a .csproj (not a .funproj file) and it's doesn't come bundled with a website or anything. I've tried .Net 4.6 and 4.6.1 as the target framework and neither have worked.

I get the following error in VSTS:

> C:\Users\Builder.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.2\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Publish.props
>   (13, 3)
>   C:\Users\Builder.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.2\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Publish.props(13,3):
>   Error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\Sdk\Sdk.Props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

There is no  node in my .csproj file so I am not sure where it is getting that from.

I'm using the latest NuGet option in VSTS, I'm using the Latest VS Version option as well.

The build steps are:

- Get Sources
- NuGet Restore
- Build Solution (MSBuild.exe exited with code '1' every time)

Is there any way to build (and then release) compiled .Net functions in VSTS at the minute?

Comment: So you are able to compile locally, just not on VSTS?

Comment: Have you tried updating your build machines with the latest SDK.  Based on the path of those errors it does not look like you are using the Hosted VS 2017 queue in VSTS.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Thanks, that seems to have been this issue. I was using a VM group called "Default" and one called "Azure" which I think might be custom VMs that we host and have added, and just named poorly. Changing to the Hosted VS 2017 build machine seems to have solved the issue. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the machine is missing the latest dotnet cli. I'm not too familiar with VSTS build machines, but you'd need to get that on there somehow https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by swapping the build agent from the "Default" group to the latest, "Hosted VS 2017" group, and that has compiled fine.